# why we need to use marker interface?

Tags: java

I just need some clarifications regarding marker interface in java.            I have read that its an empty interface in java. I just want to know why and where we need to use this. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly said, it is used to *mark* (or annotate) types with some information that the JVM compiler will use. For instance, the `Serializable` is a marker interfaces that a type must implement if it needs to have its state persisted (serialized and deserialized).